# Navigate to new page in Scrapy with the same URL

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, scrapy

I am writing a scrapy spider to scrape Rightmove, a property website. The issue I'm having is that the property search, which consists of several pages of different house listings, is all located under the same URL.

This means that the usual process of identifying the URL of the 'next' page doesn't work. Is there any way, using scrapy and not selenium (not efficient enough for the purpose) that I can navigate through the different pages? Please see my code and the source code of the relevant 'next page' button as the IMG below.

Thanks.

````
class listingsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'listings'

    start_urls = ['https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=STATION%5E1712&maxPrice=500000&radius=0.5&sortType=10&propertyTypes=&mustHave=&dontShow=&furnishTypes=&keywords=']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info('This my first spider')
        address = response.xpath('//*[@id="property-65695633"]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/a/address')
        listings = response.xpath('//h2[@class="propertyCard-title"]')

        for listing in listings:
            yield{
                'Listing': listing.get()
            }


        nextPage = response.xpath('//*[@id="l-container"]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/button/div/svg/use')
        nextPage = nextPage.get()

        pageTest = response.css('div[class=pagination-button pagination-direction pagination-direction--next] svg a::attr(href)')
        pageTest = pageTest.get()

        if pageTest is not None:
            pageTest = response.urljoin(pageTest)
            yield scrapy.Request(pageTest,callback=self.parse)

```[![enter image description here][1]][1] 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I1J1.png
````

Comment: In scrapy shell if you type view(response) you will not get any pagination. Better you click the next and find the url next, after that start from start_requests

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it turns out that each page has a unique identifier in the web-link. For example, attach `&index = 24`, this sends you to the next page.

What you need to figure out is how to include that into the request url. Some may have several pages so we increment by +24 each time to go onto the next page. However, we could increment by +24 onto infinite, therefore we use the number of page results as a way to break. It's rather sneaky to notice at first sight! but pretty easy to overcome.

Here's a scraper that can go to these next pages as requested:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Field
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links= []
for i in range(0, 480, 24):
    url = f'https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=STATION%5E1712&maxPrice=500000&radius=0.5&sortType=10&propertyTypes=&mustHave=&dontShow=&index={i}&furnishTypes=&keywords='
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    ps1 = soup.find_all('span', {'class':'searchHeader-resultCount'})
    for ps in ps1:
        if int(ps.text.strip()) > i:
            links.append(url)
        else:
            break

class ListingsItem(scrapy.Item):
    address = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    listings = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())


class listingsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'listings'
    start_urls = links
    

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url, 
                callback = self.parse
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        container = response.xpath('//div[@class="l-searchResults"]/div')
        for sales in container:
            l = ItemLoader(ListingsItem(), selector = sales)
            l.add_xpath('address', '//address[@class="propertyCard-address"]/meta[@content]')
            l.add_xpath('listings', '//h2[@class="propertyCard-title"]//text()[normalize-space()]')
            yield l.load_item()
        
        #self.logger.info('This my first spider')
        #address = response.xpath('//*[@id="property-65695633"]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/a/address')
        #listings = response.xpath('//h2[@class="propertyCard-title"]')

        #for listing in listings:
        #    yield{
        #        'Listing': listing.get()
        #    }

process = CrawlerProcess(
    settings = {
        'FEED_URI': 'rightmove.jl',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'jsonlines'
    }

)

process.crawl(listingsSpider)
process.start()
```